# Who did Sue cosplay as in Genshiken Nidaime episode 9?

Tags: genshiken

Who did Sue cosplay as in Genshiken Nidaime episode 9? It looks a bit like Canaria from *Rozen Maiden*, except the doll doesn't have a crown.

[image: Sue]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The outfit is almost identical to one of the outfits of Meruru (or, more properly, Princess Merururinsu Rede Arls), the titular character of the popular JRPG [Atelier Meruru](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atelier_Meruru:_The_Apprentice_of_Arland). Here's a comparison of the two.

Sue (ignore the fact that the background is stitched together):

[image]

Meruru in her Alchemist costume:

[image]

I don't think I need to point out the similarities, but in particular the design of the skirt, the straps on the front of the dress, the wand, the bow on the neck, the crown, the hair style, and the flowers on the outfit are all the same.

In addition, it seems that Sue's dialogue of the episode references Meruru, so there's no doubt that this is who Sue was cosplaying as.

Comment: I thought she looked like Meruru but since i didn't know which anime this was and whether Atelier Meruru was already out at the time

Comment: @Memor-X It's from Genshiken Nidaime, which is currently airing. Episode 9 just aired a couple of days ago. I don't know whether the reference is also in the manga, and if so where, but I'm pretty sure it was after 2011.

Comment: It **is** meru from artelier, the anime actually says it is, but I had no idea what that meant so I asked the question anyway.